# How to find out if my BIOS will support 3TB drives?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, nas, freenas

I want to turn an old PC into a NAS, and before I go buying 3TB hard drives, I want to check if my BIOS will support these drives. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/313515/114223) outlines some requirements.

- Mainboard: supports 48-bit LBA
- Disk controller: I'd use a PCI SATA interface for the SATA controller, since the mainboard doesn't have SATA; supports 48-bit LBA.
- BIOS: ... (?)
- It's a 32-bit system, but I want to use FreeNAS 8, so that should be OK I think (supports GPT)

But my mainboard/BIOS manual doesn't mention anything about max HDD size. How can I tell if this will work? Can I assume that since the mainboard supports 48-bit LBA the BIOS will also allow drives over 2.2TB? (It's a [MSI MS-6380E](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/KT3-Ultra--Ultra-ARU.html) mainboard with AMI BIOS).

Comment: Unless you are booting from a disk greater than 2.19TiB you do not need BIOS support. FreeBSD (and FreeNAS) will happily boot from a MBR drive. Once booted the driversfrom FreeBSd will be used to access the drives and FreeBSD understands GPT.

Comment: How do I find out if my BIOS support more than 2.19TiB boot drive? My chipset is a clumsy HM86 but I just want to know about its potential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I assume that since the mainboard supports 48-bit LBA the BIOS will also allow drives over 2.2TB?

Yes. Unless you need petabytes of space, you need not worry.